# Exporting a task file to gulpfile.js and run on command line

Tags: gulp

(Pertains to Gulp 4.0/ES6)

I would like to create a task file that can be imported by main gulpfile.js and can also be run directly from the command line using gulp (in this case without even referencing the gulpfile.js file on command line). Is this possible?

I can create a gulp task file that can be run directly:

**task-a.js:**

```
const log = require('fancy-log');

function taskA(done){
  // do stuff
  log('Executing task A');
  done();
}

exports.default = taskA;
```

Run from command line:

> gulp -f task-a.js

```
[17:53:21] Using gulpfile C:\app\task-a.js
[17:53:21] Starting 'default'...
[17:53:21] Executing task A
[17:53:21] Finished 'default' after 2.73 ms
```

OK, looks good.

---

In order to import into gulpfile.js I need to modify the export in task-a.js to:

**task-a.js:**

```
// modified the exports for require()

module.exports taskA;
```

**gulpfile.js:**

```
const taskA = require('./task-a');

gulp.task('default', taskA);
```

> gulp -f gulpfile.js

OK, this also works.

*But is it possible to change the exports in task-a.js to allow for both import and to be run from command line using gulp?*

Answer (score 0):

One way to export the function in task-a.js as a task:

```
gulp.task('default', taskA);

module.exports = gulp.series('default');
```

This ensures that the gulpfile.js can import the function as a composed operation.